# knockout: unable to update the observable array in knockout while binding to table

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-3.0

I am having two tables. In one table(parent table) I have options to add and delete rows in that one column is a dropdown column. based on the selection I need to load another table(child table) with data. I am able to do the operations on the parent table. but on the child table I am unable to push the data to the table though I can see I am able to pass the data to the child table. but the table is not populating with the data.

Here is my child table

```
<div id="childDiv">
        <table data-bind='visible: chldItem().length > 0'>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Header1</th>
                    <th>Header2</th>
                    <th />
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody data-bind='foreach: chldItem'>
                <tr>
                    <td><input class='required' data-bind='value: text, uniqueName: true' /></td>
                    <td><input class='required number' data-bind='value: defaultValue, uniqueName: true' /></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
</div>
```

Here is the View Model for child table.

```
var ChildModel = function(chldItem) {
    var self = this;
    self.chldItem = ko.observableArray([]);
    if(chldItem.length > 0){
        self.chldItem.push(chldItem);
    }
};

ko.applyBindings(new ChildModel([]), document.getElementById('childDiv'));
```

// From Parent dropdown change

```
self.childConfig.push(1, new ChildModel(clearVM);
```

Here is the fiddle with the current version of code.
http://jsfiddle.net/oneplusbot/xa90cymz/5/

I was Expecting when I choose first dropdown it will have 4 rows and for second it will show 2 rows

Comment: Hi.  Perhaps is better that you add all fiddle code here.

Comment: In your fiddle, you add elements to the observable array `childConfig`, in the `parentItem()` view model, but this array is never used, because in the `childDiv` you show a newly created `ChildModel()`.

Comment: This fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/hn2ka6ud/4/) does what you want.  The child div shows de last element selected in the dropdown.  Also, each row shows its own data, and can be changed with the dropdown.

Comment: I was able to validate. Thanks a lot